# Reflection of an under-water-object

Tags: optics, reflection

[image]I saw a photograph of a polar bear who is under the water surface. I would like to receive an explanation about the reflection of the polar bear on the water surface, which creates a second image.

Comment: Research total internal reflection.

Comment: Do you have a link to the photograph?

Comment: As @probably_someone mentioned, a better explanation can be had if you could link (or edit the post to include) the photograph.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection

Comment: Thank you very much for this link, it provides a very good explanation.

Comment: The bear is not looking at its reflection as we can see from the attached photograph.

Answer (score 1):

You get reflection at every interface between mismatched refractive indices, it is only a matter of percentage. If the surface is smooth enough and there is not too much light coming in fom above the surface to swamp out the image, a reflection will be seen.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question. I have also attached a photograph of the bear with the reflection.